# WPF: Wrapping multi-part text

Tags: wpf, textblock, word-wrap

Currently I'm using a `TextBlock` to show a single line with an image.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Image Name="StatusImage"  Stretch="Fill" MaxWidth="12" MaxHeight="12"
           Source="/Aam.Cerberus.Applications;component/Images/Warning.png"></Image>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ServiceStatusText}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text=" ("></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ServiceMachineName}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text=")"></TextBlock>
</TextBlock>
```

My questions are:

1. Is a `TextBlock` the right way to do this sort of thing?
2. How do I enable word wrapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `TextWrapping="Wrap"` property.

However, according to [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx)

> **TextBlock** is not optimized for scenarios that need to display more than a few lines of content; for such scenarios, a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) coupled with an appropriate viewing control is a better choice than **TextBlock**, in terms of performance.

Comment: I'm literally using nothing more than you see there. So would you still recommend a FlowDocument?

Comment: @Jonathan - How long is the `ServiceStatusText` message? If it's only a line or two long then you should be OK with the TextBlock.

Comment: I think the longest phrase is "ContinuePending".

Comment: @Jonathan - I'd stick with `TextBlock` then.